# CLLocation manager delegate not called despite Plist keys

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I'm writing an app in swift and need to access the user's location. I added the CLLocationManagerDelegate at the top of the class and set the delegate to self. I also added these keys in the plist because I read in iOS 8 or later it's necessary...

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription --- I need Location

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription --- I need Location

privacy - location usage description --- I need Location

It calls the first method below with no problem (called from view did load), where the delegate and request always authorization are, but then it fails to call the second(delegate) method.

```
    func determineCurrentUserLocation() {

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    location = (locations[0] as? CLLocation)!
    let long = location.coordinate.longitude
    let lat = location.coordinate.latitude

    longString = String(format: "@%", long)
    latString = String(format: "@%", lat)

    println("\(long, lat)")

}
```

Is this simply because I'm on the simulator? Would it work on a real device? Is there any way to get it to work on a simulator? Thank you!

Comment: Update: I tested it on a device and it still didn't work.

Comment: Where did you initialize the `locationManager` ?

Comment: Ha! I did forget to put locationManager = CLLocationManager() but I added that and I'm still getting the same issue.

In determineUserLocation() I added this at the top ... 

locationManager = CLLocationManager()

Comment: Did it show an alert for the user permission?

Comment: No it didn't which is odd because I did this in another app and it worked fine. The code looks good and the plist keys are there so I really wonder what I'm missing... I put a breakpoint where the location manager is initialized and the object is certainly there, but it won't call the delegate method or pop the alert view.

Comment: That is weird. I'm pretty sure all you need to add is a `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` (or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`) key to the Info.plist and it should show an alert with that value. Is the location setting available for your app in the Settings?

Comment: Not sure but that may be it, where exactly is that?

Comment: It should be in your app's settings inside the general Settings app. Or you could also go to _Privacy - Location Services_ and see if your app is there.